# AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory - IIS access using DirectoryEntry

Tags: c#, iis, access-violation, directoryentry

I was trying to find a folder under a web applicaiton in IIS using the follwing code and I met with the following error:

```
AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
```

The code I tried goes like below:

```
DirectoryEntry entry2 = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("IIS://{0}/W3SVC/{1}/Root/{2}", serverName, siteID, parentVirDirName));
entry2.RefreshCache();
DirectoryEntry entry3 = entry2.Children.Find(folderToSearch);
```

The error happens on the last line of the code above.
Any help or clue to get out of this is highly appreciated

Comment: What are you passing as folderToSearch?

Comment: It is a string with the folder name in first level in the current web application